# Class 'Kreait\Firebase\Factory' not found

Tags: php, firebase

> I am trying to use Firebase PHP Admin SDK. I am facing this error everytime :

```
 Class 'Kreait\Firebase\Factory' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Web\dbcon.php on line 7
```

> I ran all the following commands successfully. Also, I have composer installed as well.
> Commands I tried :

- composer require kreait/firebase-php
- composer update

> This is my `dbcon.php` file :

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
   
    $factory = (new Factory)
           ->withServiceAccount('testpanel-9c804-firebase-adminsdk-dt1ag-52fdf4fca0.json')
           ->withDatabaseUri('https://testpanel-9c804-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com');
    
           $database = $factory->createDatabase();
       
    ?>
```

> This is the index.php file :

```
    <?php
    include('dbcon.php');


    $reference = $database->getReference('contacts');

    echo $reference-> getValue();
   ?>
```

> How to fix this error. Pls help

Comment: Is the dbcon.php file in the same folder as the vendor dir?

Comment: yes, dbcon.php is in the root folder